# How to work Supervision strategy after recover at non-linear graphs in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I use recover method to catch error or exceptions in Akka Streams. It's work at linear graph but not non-linear graph(e.g. Broadcast, Zip).
The reason why Graph with fan-in or fan-out wait failure port forever, so Akka Streams hangs up.
The solution is described at section 9 in https://blog.softwaremill.com/akka-streams-pitfalls-to-avoid-part-2-f93e60746c58.

That post uses Try monad and catch Exception in Flow. That works. However I use recover method because I have many flows and I want to catch error in one place.

I prepare below example, but not work...

```
Source(1 to 10)
  .via(graph)
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
  .runForeach(println)

private def dangerFlow: Flow[Int, Try[String], NotUsed] = {
  Flow[Int].map(a => if (a == 5) throw new Exception("5 is invalid") else a.toString).map(str => Try(str)).recover {
    case e => Failure[String](e)
  }
}

private def safeFlow: Flow[Int, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].map( "hello" +_)

def graph = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val zip = b.add(Zip[Try[String], String])

  bcast.out(0) ~> dangerFlow ~> zip.in0
  bcast.out(1) ~> safeFlow ~> zip.in1

  FlowShape(bcast.in, zip.out)
})
```

Result:

```
(Success(1),hello1)
(Success(2),hello2)
(Success(3),hello3)
(Success(4),hello4)
```

I expected:

```
(Success(1),hello1)
(Success(2),hello2)
(Success(3),hello3)
(Success(4),hello4)
(Failure(java.lang.Exception: 5 is invalid),hello5)
(Success(6),hello6)
(Success(7),hello7)
(Success(8),hello8)
(Success(9),hello9)
(Success(10),hello10)
```

Please tell me any solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's add a couple of print statements to more clearly see what's going on: one at the completion of the stream...

```
val stream =
  Source(1 to 10)
    .via(graph)
    .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
    .runForeach(println)

// ...

stream.onComplete { _ =>
  println("Done!") // <---
  system.terminate()
}
```

...and another in the `recover` block:

```
private def dangerFlow: Flow[Int, Try[String], NotUsed] = {
  Flow[Int]
    .map(a => if (a == 5) throw new Exception("5 is invalid") else a.toString)
    .map(str => Try(str))
    .recover {
      case e =>
        println("Recovering...") // <---
        Failure[String](e)
    }
}
```

The output of running the stream is...

```
(Success(1),hello1)
(Success(2),hello2)
(Success(3),hello3)
(Success(4),hello4)
// no "Recovering..." or "Done!"
```

...showing that the `recover` method is not called and the stream never completes. The stream deadlocks for the same reason as what the [blog](https://blog.softwaremill.com/akka-streams-pitfalls-to-avoid-part-2-f93e60746c58) describes:

> - [`dangerFlow`] fails and does not emit element to `Zip`. It then resumes demanding next element from `broadcast`. However, for `broadcast` to emit element the demand must be signaled from all outputs.
> - `Zip` receives only one element (from `safeFlow`) and waits forever for the second element. `Zip` emits only when both inputs have value.

The resuming supervision strategy is the reason that `recover` is not invoked. Removing that strategy...

```
val stream =
  Source(1 to 10)
    .via(graph)
    //.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
    .runForeach(println)
```

...and running the stream again produces the following output:

```
(Success(1),hello1)
(Success(2),hello2)
(Success(3),hello3)
(Success(4),hello4)
Recovering...
(Failure(java.lang.Exception: 5 is invalid),hello5)
Done!
```

Now `recover` is called, and the stream completes, but the stream is truncated. This is because [`recover`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-error.html#recover) completes the stream:

> `recover` allows you to emit a final element and then complete the stream on an upstream failure.

To get the desired behavior, you have to use `Try` as follows:

```
private def dangerFlow: Flow[Int, Try[String], NotUsed] = {
  Flow[Int].map(a => if (a == 5) Failure(new Exception("5 is invalid")) else Try(a.toString))
}
```

Running the stream with the above `Flow` produces the following:

```
(Success(1),hello1)
(Success(2),hello2)
(Success(3),hello3)
(Success(4),hello4)
(Failure(java.lang.Exception: 5 is invalid),hello5)
(Success(6),hello6)
(Success(7),hello7)
(Success(8),hello8)
(Success(9),hello9)
(Success(10),hello10)
Done!
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I understood `recover` "complete" the stream, so `recover` isn't invoke if supervision strategy is resuming.
I have to use `Try` instead of propagating exception.